# При загрузке сайта на моб.у. в браузере Chrome сайт не редиректит на мобильную версию и просто застревает

Tags: javascript, css, redirect

Обычно, в любом браузере, открывает сайт miksonphoto.ru с моб.у. и редиректит на папку tablet где хранится сайт, но у определенных пользователей сайт просто не реагирует, остается белый экран и не открывается ничего.

- не работает только у определенного кол-ва пользователей
- если удалить почистить кеш и удалить апдейты хрома, все работает
- в консоли разработчика в консоли просто пусто, в вкладке network статус 
  потом 200 потом cancelled все с js / css

например

> ```
> site_global.css?crc=443350757   (canceled)  stylesheet  (index) 0 B 36ms
> runScript.js    (canceled)  script  runScript-injecter.js:22    0 B 3 ms
> ```

не понимаю куда копать...

Comment: я думаю грешите на какой нибудь воедоносный код или adblock

Comment: кто делает редирект? Я перешел и редиректа не произошло, остался на том же урле, только подгрузка всех скриптов отменилась, как вы описали. Скорее всего редиректа нет, т.к. html возвращается пустой, а редирект идет в js. Проверял в хроме в debug bar. Может быть на сервере настроено какое-нибудь кеширование или ответ в зависимости от user-agent

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась в кривом скрипте, который автоматически создавала программа Adobe Muse. Скрипт определял заходит ли пользователь с мобильного устройства, и если да, то перенаправлял на сайт для моб.у.

Решилось благодоря более грамотному скрипту, который нужно вручную поместить в метаданные в программе и отключении редиректа в  настройках сайта, чтобы программа не писала свой код редиректа.

Подробно по ссылке: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2630698